# Distribution of the ratio of two i.i.d standard normals

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I am reading an article in which the author states that given two i.i.d random variables $X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we have $\mathbb{P}(\frac{X}{Y}\le t)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{X}{|Y|}\le t)$ since the random varaibles $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}$ are identically distributed by the symmetry of the standard normal distribution.

But I don't really understand why the random variables $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}$ are identically distributed. Can you provide a reason for why these two random variables are identically distributed?